# jQuery function does not work on appended html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append a div with jQuery and then use jQuery click function on a class which is inside the appended div. Here's my code, it does not work if I append the div, however it works fine if the div already exists in the html.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="add">
    Add item
</div>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var box = '<div class="box"><div class="remove">x</div></div>'
    $('.container').append(box)
});


$('.remove').click(function(){
    alert("remove");
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Y625A/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use event delegation

```
$('.container').on('click','.remove',function(){
    alert("remove");
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/Y625A/2/

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: can i use $('.remove').on('click',function(){
    alert("remove");
});

Comment: Why sir.Here also we are using .on.Can u explain pls

Comment: @user1251698, it works, it just logs to the console, look at your console

Comment: see on console..i replaced alert with console.log

Answer (score 1):

Try using `live` to bind the events, this will bind them when the new items are created:

```
$('.add').live('click', function(e){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the click even once you create the element:

```
$('.add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var box = "<div class='box'><div class='remove'>x</div></div>"
    $('.container').append(box)

$('.remove').click(function(){
    alert("remove");
});


});
```

http://jsbin.com/ofoteq/1/edit

Comment: You can, but don't have to, as pXL's answer demonstrates.

Comment: I was referring to your wording. Also, you'll end up with multiple binds if you add multiple items (because you are binding to every `.remove` every time one is added). You should bind directly to the box element you create instead.